# how to add arrows to Slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

[image]

I am putting together a slide presentation using a jquery plugin called 'slick' (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) using django and a bootstrap 3 template. I've got a basic carousel working  using a django template that looks like:

```
  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div><IMG src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSj2c33fdt1ugB8VBuE5V37wnmPoxWMknX9JnGycNiH2yr3BpDKVA"></div>


    <div>your content</div>
  </div>
```

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/20a90mdm/1/

I'm wondering if there is a way to add arrows to the left and right of the slide, like in the first example (Single Item) on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ . I can only see the prev and next buttons below the slides

Answer (score 2):

Your arrows are already there, they are the **Previous** and **Next** buttons at the bottom of the page. You would need to include slick-theme.css or style them by yourself via css.

Comment: Ya they are there. You just need to style them

Comment: OK, I've included the slick theme, as well as bootstrap3 ( http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/20a90mdm/2/ ), but I don't see any change.

Comment: That is because it's not being loaded correctly, I mean the css file. And even if you would load the slick-theme.css, you'd still want to style the .slick-prev and .slick-next classes with a background, like background: url('images/prev_arrow.png');

Comment: Hi Brance, I don't know much CSS. why is it not being loaded correctly? I don't see any errors in my console.

Answer (score 2):

Here I try css code...

```
    .slick-prev{
    background:#000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
.slick-next{
    background:#000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

**NOTE**

Give their parent class

> position:relative

Also you can set **left & right** position as your need.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the buttons in slick-theme.css is white, so not visible on a white background.

Change the color of the buttons there or overwrite in your own style sheet like this:

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    color: #000000;
}
```